# Why am I not able to use "Routes" from react-router-dom even though it is version 6? It shows error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, version

I have been trying to us 'Routes' from react-router-dom like this `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';`  And I call it here:

```
const NavPage = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <section>
        <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/goals" element={<Goals />} />
        <Route path="/meetings" element={<Meetings />} />
        <Route path="/tasks" element={<Tasks />} />
        <Route path="/reviews" element={<Reviews />} />
        <Route path="/feedback" element={<Feedback />} />
        <Route path="/recognitions" element={<Recognitions />} />
        <Route path="/notes" element={<Notes />} />
        </Routes>
      </section>      
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

And it throws an error:
`export 'Routes' (imported as 'Routes') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Prompt, Redirect, Route, Router, StaticRouter, Switch, generatePath, matchPath, useHistory, useLocation, useParams, useRouteMatch, withRouter)`

My react-router-dom version is 6
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI9JP.png)

I tried using `Switch` but it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

According to the image you have `react-router-dom@^5.1.2` installed.

[image]

The latest version is v6.8.0. It looks like your IDE is just informing you what the latest version is when you hover over that dependency.

If you want to use the v6.8.0 then you'll need to actually install it and update your project's package.json file.

From the terminal in the project's root directly run the following command to update to v.6.8.0 and update the package.json file.

```
npm install --save react-router-dom@latest
```

From here the project should have all the RRDv6 components available to it.

`react-router-dom` re-exports all of `react-router` so there's no need to have is listed additionally as a dependency, especially if it is still the previous version. If `react-router` is installed, uninstall it, then install `react-router-dom@6`.

```
npm uninstall --save react-router
```

Comment: I did everything as you mentioned. Updated the package.json as well. The error still persists
`Attempted import error: 'Routes' is not exported from 'react-router-dom' (imported as 'Routes').
ERROR in ./src/components/sample/NavPage.jsx 19:39-45
export 'Routes' (imported as 'Routes') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Prompt, Redirect, Route, Router, StaticRouter, Switch, generatePath, matchPath, useHistory, useLocation, useParams, useRouteMatch, withRouter)`

Comment: I run all the comments you gave and updated the package.json to `"react-router-dom": "^6.8.0",`

Comment: @rayst4rk Are you sure you are installed dependencies in the correct directory? Updating the correct package.json file? Try deleting the `node_modules` directory and running `npm i` to reinstall all dependencies.

Comment: Actually.. I m new to react.. so just to confirm.. will deleting `node_modules` crash my project? Also is there something else I can use instead of Routes from RRD. 
Basically my intention is to direct to a different page onClick of a tab. 
On the tab i used Navlink

Comment: @rayst4rk It won't crash the app. When you run `npm install` is will recreate that directory when the project dependencies are installed. Routes are how you render specific content based on the URL path, I'm not sure I really understand that part of your question.

Comment: Still doesn't work :(

Comment: @rayst4rk Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that we could inspect live?